# Escape character in DataWeave string

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

We are getting a value from a DB that contains a backslash (\). After going through DataWeave, we get 2 backslashes. Here it is how it looks:

[image]

How can we have only one backslash in the end? Can we use the replace function somehow? I tried and could not make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the reason why you see two backslashes is because backslash is a reserved character (see JSON [spec](http://json.org/)) therefore DataWeave is automatically escaping the backslash, which is necessary so not to have your DB value corrupted.

In my opinion the double backslash is not a problem. You should get the right content upon consuming the JSON object.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It is the JSON spec that demands it more or less. With one backslash is invalid JSON and it will not get parsed by a client.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to put in an escape character of your choice

Eg: `%output application/csv escape = " "`

This should ideally replace `"/"` with `" "`.

Hope this helps.